# return match record of array value and group by other property in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

we are using **mongoDB** NoSQl database with NPM library **Mongoose** and **Nodejs**.

I have collection called "**USERS**"  and having document format like below:

```
{user_number: 12, region:"Pune"},
{user_number: 13, region:"Mumbai"},
{user_number: 14, region:"Mumbai"},
{user_number: 15, region:"Punjab"},
{user_number: 16, region:"Delhi"},
{user_number: 17, region:"Pune"}
```

I am having array of `user_Number=[12,13,14,15]` so I would like to return matching record of **user_number** with **group by region**.
User_number array is dynamic.

Expected output is :

```
{"data":{
 {
            "_id": {
                "region": "pune"
            },
            "count": 1,
            "region": "Pune"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "region": "Mumbai"
            },
            "count": 2,
            "region": "Mumbai"
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "region": "Punjab"
            },
            "count": 1,
            "region": "Punjab"
        },
      }
}
```

Could you please someone guide me with best approach ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$match` and `$group` in your aggeration pipeline to do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      user_number: {
        $in: [12,13,14,15]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$region",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can try this on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/tXpwtngnU1B

Comment: Could you please guide me on this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63918199/mongoose-date-comparing-without-time-and-group-by-multiple-properties

Comment: Done - pls check. I'm on my mobile so I can't test right now.