# mongoose Date comparing without time and Group by multiple properties?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Might be question is look like duplicate but apologize for it. Because our business case is different than existing question.

We are using the **Nodejs** and **MongoDB** for writing the REST API.

I am having collection called : **EMPLog** with following document object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5dp"),
    "staffId" : 12345,
    "category" : "trend",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rer",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5de"),
    "staffId" : 12346,
    "category" : "incident",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rergfhfhf",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5dc"),
    "staffId" : 12347,
    "category" : "trend",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rerrwe",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5dr"),
    "staffId" : 12348,
    "category" : "trend",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rerrwe",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

we are receiving the input from as **category** and **createdAt** from user. **createdAt** is receiving without time.

Suppose , User is providing the category as **trend**  and createdAt as **2020-08-13** then We have to group by **trend**,**createdAt** and **staffId** and return the **staffId** as array.

note: **Category** and **CreatedAt** will receiving dynamic/runtime from user.

Expected result is: `{data:{staffIds:[12345,12347]}}`

if anyone can guide me then it will be great help.

Thanks in Advance to All Experts.

Comment: hello, please staffIds is the category !

Comment: Hi there! It sounds like you are trying to filter out the EMPLog documents using the `createdAt` field without considering the time component of the date value, is that correct?

Comment: @ChouaibSeghier are you talking about expected result key "staffIds"?

Comment: @Tunmee Yes CreatedAt  and category fields matching and grouping of category,staffId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to match the given `category` and `createdAt`-date using `$match`, then group and finally use `$addToSet` to get all the unique `staffId`s:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "category": "trend",
      "createdAt": {$gte: new Date("2020-08-13T00:00:00Z"), $lt: ISODate("2020-08-14T00:00:00Z")}
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "staffIds": {
        "$addToSet": "$staffId"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Here's an example on mongoplayground (had to use strings and regex for the date as ISODate is not supported there): https://mongoplayground.net/p/oGM7cfvCRQx

Comment: if I will add same staffId with same date then it will return duplicate staffId. so How we can group staffId so it will not return duplicate staffId for same date

Comment: You can use `$addToSet` instead of `$push` :)

Comment: thanks lot. you have saved my day. great help in mongodb

Comment: Could you please guide me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496424/unable-to-update-the-createdat-property-in-mongoose

Comment: Could you please help on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285364/mongoose-date-comparing-without-time-and-group-by-createdat-and-staffid-with-wee