# unable to update the createdAt property in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, data-migration

**Hello All expert ,**

Might be question seem duplicate but mine business case is little different, Please, bear with me.

I am working old Schema defined by other developer where `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties are missing. so I have updated the schema by adding the `{ timestamps: true }`. whenever I am creating new document then there is no problem. it is working as expected but existing/old documents are there so I am trying to  add `createdAt` properties by writing separate script and reading created time from `_id` property like `_id.getTimestamp()`. I am able to extract created time from _id but unable to add `createdAt` property in existing document. old documents/data is very crucial but business is expecting to add `createdAt` propery to old document.

I am using **mongoose NPM** library and version is : `"mongoose": "^5.9.16",`

Schema  sample as below:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const profileSchema = new Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        profile_number: {
          type: Number
        },
        view: {
          type: String
        },
     
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
module.exports = mongoose.model("profile", profileSchema, "profile");
```

Script to add **createdAt** property with extracting the timestamp from **_id**

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Profile= require("../../models/Profile/ProfileModel");
    
    /****
     * * Fetch all Portfolios List
     * */
    exports.getAllProfileList = async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
    
        const profileResult = await Profile.find({},{_id:1}).exec(); //return all ids
        const timeStampExtract = await profileResult.map(item => {
          console.log("Item is:", item._id.getTimestamp());
// trying to update createdAt time by extacting item._id.getTimestamp()
          Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: item._id },
            { $set: { createdAt: item._id.getTimestamp() } },
            { upsert: true }
          )
            .then(res => console.log("Response:"))
            .catch(error => console.log("Error is:", error.message));
          return item._id.getTimestamp();
        });
   
        if (!profileResult ) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ message: "Unable to find profile list", statusCode: 400 });
        }
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({ totalCount: profileResult.length, data: timeStampExtract });
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message, statusCode: 500 });
      }
    };
```

is By-default **createdAt** is immutable ?

Could some someone help with it? It will be great help.

Thanks to All experts

Comment: when we are using  { timestamps: true } inside schema it is adding createdAt and updatedAt properties to document. i guess ,createdAt is immutable since it is not allow to update value. if we will add other key apart from createdAt name like created_At it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some of the documents were created when the `timestamps` option was set to false (this is the default value) mongoose will not know those timestamps. Hence, `item._id.getTimestamp()` will return undefined.

What you can do, is to recreate the entries where `createdAt` does not exist. Mongoose will then automatically generate the timestamps and set them to the current timestamp, if the option is enabled:

```
    const profilesWithoutCreated = await Profile.find({createdAt: {$exists: false}}).exec();
    const timeStampExtract = [];
    let newProfile;
    for (const profile of profiles) {
       newProfile = new Profile(profile);
       newProfile.createdAt = profile._id.getTimestamp();
       const savedProfile = await newProfile.save();
       timeStampExtract.push(savedProfile._id.getTimestamp());
    }
```

Comment: it is not working, I have tried it. createdAt is not adding

Comment: when we are using { timestamps: true } inside schema it is adding createdAt and updatedAt properties to document. i guess ,createdAt is immutable since it is not allow to update value. if we will add other key apart from createdAt name like created_At it is working

Comment: it is working on save model. thanks for continues help. I have made small change in answer. Please, review it

Comment: Could you please help me on it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285364/mongoose-date-comparing-without-time-and-group-by-createdat-and-staffid-with-wee