# mongoose Date comparing without time and Group by createdAt and staffId with Weekly, monthly and Yearly total of staff count by aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, rest

Might be question is look like duplicate but apologize for it.

I want to aggregate the weekly, Monthly, Yearly result basis of `createdAt` property without time  and `staffId`.

**Model is like below:**

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5dp"),
    "staffId" : 12345,
    "category" : "trend",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rer",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5de"),
    "staffId" : 12346,
    "category" : "incident",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rergfhfhf",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-14T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-08T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5dc"),
    "staffId" : 12347,
    "category" : "trend",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rerrwe",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-13T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f351f3d9d90b1281c44c5dr"),
    "staffId" : 12348,
    "category" : "trend",
    "page_route" : "http://example.com/rerrwe",
    "expireAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.196Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-08-08T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-08-12T11:08:45.199Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Expected result:
**Example 1) Weekly**

```
[
{_id: "2020-11-13", total: 2},
{_id: "2020-11-8", total: 2},


]
```

**Example 2) Monthly**

```
[
{_id: "2020-11-8", total: 4},

]
```

similarly for yearly ...

I am using **nodejs** and **mongoose** to implement the **API**.

I am struggle lot but I am unable to achieve the expected result.

if anyone help me then it will be great help.

Thanks to all Expert.

I have tried something like this:

```
[
        {
          $match: {
            createdAt: { $gte: new Date(currentDate), $lt: new Date(nextDate) }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            staffId: 1,
            day: {
              $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"
            },
            month: {
              $month: "$createdAt"
            },
            year: {
              $year: "$createdAt"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            staffId: 1,
            datetime: {
              $concat: [
                {
                  $substr: ["$year", 0, 4]
                },
                "-",
                {
                  $substr: ["$month", 0, 2]
                },
                "-",
                {
                  $substr: ["$day", 0, 2]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              createdAt: "$datetime",
              staffId: "$staffId"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {$week:"$_id.createdAt"},
            total: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
      ];
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit , I have updated in question. Could you please guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try,

- Group by week

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
        week: { $week: "$createdAt" }
      },
      createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xqIxsLe9Jw6)

- Group by month

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: "$createdAt" },
        month: { $month: "$createdAt" }
      },
      createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yI-x1iOF9GN)

- Group by year

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $year: "$createdAt" },
      createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gCabYZ_q1Oh)

> You can change date format from your client side language using `createdAt` field!

Comment: there is small issue, if same staffid is occurring many time in same date  then it should be return 1 count because same time we want to have group by with createdAt and staffId. how we can achieve that

Comment: You can group by staffId as well like this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IEcAZP5WcdB), if this is not your expectation can you please provide expected result.